# Bootstrap responsive resizing issue with Nav Bar

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md fixed-top whitelight nav-masthead">
  <a class="navbar-brand gold-text" href="companyName.php">Company Name</a>

  <!--Creates  a clickable button with a toggle icon once the screen collapses-->
  <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarCollapse" aria-controls="navbarCollapse" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>

  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse d-inline-flex justify-content-end" id="navbarSupportedContent">
   <ul class="navbar-nav">
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link text-black"  style="font-size:16px"; href="login.php">Login <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
    </li>
      <a class="nav-link text-black" style="font-size:16px"; href="signup.php">Sign Up<a>
    <li class="nav-item">
    </li>
   </ul>
  </div>
  </header>
```

Trying to get a nav bar with the company name on the left and the login and sign up button on the right. I used a hyperlink for the company name which works fine and is left-aligned and shows when you resize the browser so it resembles iPad.

However, I used a flex-box for the div with the list containing the login and sign up links. This works with normal browsers but when you resize I get this:

[image: [![enter image description here][1]][ [1]:]

How can I fix this? I also want to have an image below but that won't show up either.

Comment: anyone got any ideas please?

Comment: Is your issue that the menu stays open on the resize with the hamburger icon above it?

Comment: @JeffBerlin yep, well I can't get the login and Sign up to be on the right hand side of the page and in the instance that I do manage to do so, I end up with login above signup as shown in my image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start by removing `.d-inline-flex` on the `div` and that should keep the menu closed when the hamburger icon is shown in the responsive breakdown:

```css
/* this aligns the UL to the right when hamburger is clicked */
.navbar-nav {
  text-align: right;
}
```

```html
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-JcKb8q3iqJ61gNV9KGb8thSsNjpSL0n8PARn9HuZOnIxN0hoP+VmmDGMN5t9UJ0Z" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>
<body>
  <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-light bg-light">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbrand</a>
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarTogglerDemo02" aria-controls="navbarTogglerDemo02" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
      <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse justify-content-end" id="navbarTogglerDemo02">
      <ul class="navbar-nav">
        <li class="nav-item active">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Login <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Sign Up</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </nav>
  
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.1/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-9/reFTGAW83EW2RDu2S0VKaIzap3H66lZH81PoYlFhbGU+6BZp6G7niu735Sk7lN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-B4gt1jrGC7Jh4AgTPSdUtOBvfO8shuf57BaghqFfPlYxofvL8/KUEfYiJOMMV+rV" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for this. When I copy and paste it (without the cdn since I have it installed) I get the Nav Bar not spanning the entire way. Also the Navbar Toggler seems invisible? Just a bit lost but thanks so much.

Comment: Is it wrapped in a `.container`?

Comment: Nope I copied and pasted it directly. Also when I press the hamburger icon it just seems to stay there and won't decollapse. Frustrating day.

Comment: You must have other code causing an issue. My guess is that your `jQuery` isn't implemented properly. Any chance you can update your question with the `link`'s and `script`'s for Bootstrap and jQuery?

Comment: <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-JcKb8q3iqJ61gNV9KGb8thSsNjpSL0n8PARn9HuZOnIxN0hoP+VmmDGMN5t9UJ0Z" crossorigin="anonymous">

Comment: <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.1/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-9/reFTGAW83EW2RDu2S0VKaIzap3H66lZH81PoYlFhbGU+6BZp6G7niu735Sk7lN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-B4gt1jrGC7Jh4AgTPSdUtOBvfO8shuf57BaghqFfPlYxofvL8/KUEfYiJOMMV+rV" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

Comment: I attached them here.

Comment: Just seems to be the icon that doesn't load up for me but does when I use your code on stack overflow.

Comment: Just for curiosity, why did you remove d-inline-flex please?

Comment: Whenever you add the `flex` class to it, the menu will remain in view